# Remove duplicate address_id from sql data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get only distinct address_id in result no duplication. Here is my query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT address.address_id, address.address1, address.streetcity, state.stateabbrev, rtrim(ltrim(case when address.streetzipcode is not null and address.streetzipcode != 'NULL' then address.streetzipcode else '' end))+case when len(address.streetzipplus4)>0 then '-'+rtrim(ltrim(address.streetzipplus4)) else '' end as streetzipcode, address.homephone,
        dbo.f_addressstudent (student.address_id) as Students, 
        dbo.f_addresspeople (student.address_id) as Adults,
        case 
            when @classif_id IS NULL then 0 
            else 
            student.classif_id 
        end classif,
        classifctn
    FROM district WITH(NOLOCK) 
        JOIN dbo.building ON building.district_id = district.district_id 
        JOIN dbo.studbldg_bridge WITH(NOLOCK) ON studbldg_bridge.bldg_id=building.bldg_id
        JOIN dbo.student WITH(NOLOCK) ON student.student_id = studbldg_bridge.student_id
        JOIN classif with(nolock) on student.classif_id = classif.classif_id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.address WITH(NOLOCK) ON student.address_id = address.address_id 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.state WITH(NOLOCK) ON address.streetstate_id = state.state_id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.state AS mailstate WITH(NOLOCK) ON address.state_id = mailstate.state_id
    WHERE district.district_id = (SELECT district_id FROM dbo.building WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE bldg_id = @bldg_id)
    ORDER BY classif,Adults, Students
```

Here is result of query
[Query result with error in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DryD.png)

I have tried to group by and use aggregate function with address_id but I also have non-aggregate columns so it didn't worked for me.
After that I also tried using OVER(partition by address.address_id) but it also didn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated in advance.

Thank you

**UPDATE on Business logic/Requirements **

I need to get unique addresses for parents of students. As parent can have two or more children living in same address, it causes duplication. I need to get only one child per parent in other words.

Comment: When there are duplicates, how should the classification (for example) be determined? Without actually fully defining your requirements, it's impossible to get a "correct" answer.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because if you are trying a window function OVER(partition....) it means you are not using it as window functions do not exist in mysql.  Please only tag the rdbms you are actually using.

Comment: I am updating question to give you more information on requirements.

Comment: Off topic; avoid using the table hint [NOLOCK](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).  It can, and eventually will, return records that never existed within the committed database.

Answer (score 0):

From your image of the results it looks like the `classifctn` column has more than 1 value so it is repeating your row by that.  In order to get 1 distinct address_id and rest of the columns either remove it from your query or you can set a precedence that will only return 1 record per address_id

further please tag only the RDBMs you ware actually using.  MySQL for example doesn't have window functions yet you tagged it yet referenced using OVER(partition.... which would not be possible in mysql

```
;WITH cte (
    SELECT DISTINCT address.address_id, address.address1, address.streetcity, state.stateabbrev, rtrim(ltrim(case when address.streetzipcode is not null and address.streetzipcode != 'NULL' then address.streetzipcode else '' end))+case when len(address.streetzipplus4)>0 then '-'+rtrim(ltrim(address.streetzipplus4)) else '' end as streetzipcode, address.homephone,
          dbo.f_addressstudent (student.address_id) as Students, 
          dbo.f_addresspeople (student.address_id) as Adults,
          case 
             when @classif_id IS NULL then 0 
             else 
             student.classif_id 
          end classif,
          classifctn,

          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY address.address_id ORDER BY HOW WILL YOU CHOOSE?) AS RowNum

       FROM district WITH(NOLOCK) 
          JOIN dbo.building ON building.district_id = district.district_id 
          JOIN dbo.studbldg_bridge WITH(NOLOCK) ON studbldg_bridge.bldg_id=building.bldg_id
          JOIN dbo.student WITH(NOLOCK) ON student.student_id = studbldg_bridge.student_id
          JOIN classif with(nolock) on student.classif_id = classif.classif_id
          LEFT JOIN dbo.address WITH(NOLOCK) ON student.address_id = address.address_id 
          LEFT JOIN dbo.state WITH(NOLOCK) ON address.streetstate_id = state.state_id
          LEFT JOIN dbo.state AS mailstate WITH(NOLOCK) ON address.state_id = mailstate.state_id
       WHERE district.district_id = (SELECT district_id FROM dbo.building WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE bldg_id = @bldg_id)
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
ORDER BY
    classif
    ,Adults
    ,Students
```

Alternatively you could nest your select query.  note though this solution is somewhat useless as it will only return 1 grade/`classifctn` when more than 1 exists in a household if you really don't care about the column then you should just remove it from your query.

Actually both your classifctn and classif columns will cause you multiple rows when more than 1 student is at the same address.  here is a way to concatenate those values to a single row.  You should spend some more time on your business case and defining it for us.  But here is one example for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    address.address_id
    ,address.address1
    ,address.streetcity
    ,state.stateabbrev
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(NULLIF(address.streetzipcode,'NULL'),'')))
       + CASE WHEN LEN(address.streetzipplus4) > 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END
       + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(address.streetzipplus4,''))) AS streetzipcode
    ,address.homephone
    ,dbo.f_addressstudent (student.address_id) as Students
    ,dbo.f_addresspeople (student.address_id) as Adults
    , case 
       when @classif_id IS NULL then 0 
       else student.classif_id 
      end classif

        ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST(classif_id AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM
            classif c
        WHERE c.classif = student.classif
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'') AS classifs

        ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST(classifctn AS VARCHAR(100))
        FROM
            classif c
        WHERE c.classif = student.classif
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'') AS classifctns
FROM
    district WITH(NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN dbo.building
    ON building.district_id = district.district_id
    AND building.bldg_id = @bldg_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.student WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON student.student_id = studbldg_bridge.student_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.address WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON student.address_id = address.address_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.state WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON address.streetstate_id = state.state_id
```

Note I when ahead and changed the zip code logic to show you some use of `ISNULL()` and `NULLIF()` that are helpful in cases like that.  I also removed 3 tables because 2 are not used and the third ends up being used in a subselect to concatenate the values.  Also address table was changed to an INNER JOIN because if an address doesn't exist all of the other information becomes blank/useless....

```
INNER JOIN dbo.studbldg_bridge WITH(NOLOCK) ON studbldg_bridge.bldg_id=building.bldg_id    
    LEFT JOIN dbo.state AS mailstate WITH(NOLOCK) ON address.state_id = mailstate.state_id
    INNER JOIN classif with(nolock) on student.classif_id = classif.classif_id
```

Comment: I need this information in result set, cannot be removed.How can I set a precedence?

Comment: that is entirely up to you, how will you determine which classifctn is the one you want?  If you say you want both then do you want to concatenate the rows to a single comma separated string?  If the former you could use a row_number() OVER(partition by address_id) and then select where = 1 from cte or nested query. And in the latter I would use either a recursive cte or XML PATH with a sub select.  Note you have to tag the exact database you are using as the answers will varry.

Comment: Actually I did try row_number() OVER (order by address_id) . But when in where clause I tried to access abc it gives me error which says "invalid column"

Comment: you cannot use window functions in WHERE clause you would add it to the select list of your first query and then make that a cte or a nested query and then query where column alias for row_number() = 1 see my answer I will put in the structure in just a second

Comment: I provided some examples that may give you some direction.  Clean up your business logic for additional help. good luck

Comment: Nice it will help me.